# How np.argpartition works ??? and how is it different from np.argsort

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Given an array arr, find the top 4 maximum values.

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([90, 14, 24, 13, 13, 590, 0, 45, 16, 50])
```

the expected output is `[ 45 50 590 90]`

but I'm getting `[45 50 90 590]` after applying `np.argsort`

Comment: It found the same 4 values, but didn't sort them.  That's what the docs promise.

Comment: what is the significance of kth in argpartition

Comment: why do you want result like that?